# Spring autowiring classes between 2 distinct project

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

I'm trying to autowire classes between 2 projects with spring (using eclipse IDE). So I added to the first project the second project to the build path. The imports are resolved correctly but when I launch the app the log tells me that he can't find the class which I'm trying to wire to.

Comment: Did you import the first projects context into the second one's?

Comment: The build path is not enough. you must define the classpath as well... is it a standalone or JEE application?

Comment: I do not import the first into the second, and I don't see why it will be usefull. And JEE app, how can I edit the classpath ?

Comment: Nevermind I found the classpath.

Comment: I order to autowire a class from one project in another project, you need to have that bean present in the second projects context. One way to do that is to import the first project's context into the second projects context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath have solved the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).